# iteration and matching items in lists

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, iteration

Am trying to check if elements of a list match elements of another. But there is a slight twist to the problem.

```
alist = ['949', '714']
blist = ['(714)824-1234', '(419)312-8732', '(949)555-1234', '(661)949-2867']
```

Am trying to match the elements of alist to the blist, but only the area code part(in blist). Here is my current code:

```
def match_area_codes(alist, blist):
clist =[]
for i in alist:
    for j in blist:
        if i in j:
            clist.append(j)
return clist
```

The code works for the most part, except when there is a string matching the area code anywhere else in the list. It should only print:

```
['(714)824-1234', '(949)555-1234']
```

but it ends up printing

```
['(714)824-1234', '(949)555-1234', '(661)949-2867']
```

as there is a '949' in the last phone number. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to get the part within `(...)` and compare that part to `alist`.

```
import re
def match_area_codes(alist, blist):
    p = re.compile(r"\((\d+)\)")
    return [b for b in blist if p.search(b).group(1) in alist]
```

Example:

```
>>> alist = set(['949', '714'])
>>> blist = ['(714)824-1234', '(419)312-8732', '(949)555-1234', '(661)949-2867']
>>> match_area_codes(alist, blist)
['(714)824-1234', '(949)555-1234']
```

---

If you *really really* want to do it without regular expressions, you could, e.g., find the position of the `(` and `)` and thus get the slice from the string corresponding to the region code.

```
def match_area_codes(alist, blist):
    find_code = lambda s: s[s.index("(") + 1 : s.index(")")]
    return [b for b in blist if find_code(b) in alist]
```

However, I would *strongly* suggest to just take this as an opportunity for getting started with regular expressions. It's not all that hard, and definitely worth it!

Comment: Using `re.compile` is a better idea than putting that in list comprehension!and compile the regex in each iteration!

Comment: @Kasra Yes, that's why I used `re.compile` instead of putting it in the list comprehension... or what do you mean?

Comment: @tobias_k..just so..is there an alternative way? I haven't gone through regular expressions yet.

Comment: @LeonSurrao You mean an alternative to regular expressions? Sure there is, but you should just take this as the opportunity to get through regular expression. It's worth it!

Comment: @tobias_k..I meant just using for and if statements, split or join.

Comment: nm..I figured it out.